# Is there a way to "manipulate" my location without third parties knowing it? (when i am logged in to my google account)

Tags: vpn, dns, google, openvpn

Is there a way to "manipulate" my location (IP address) without third parties knowing it? (when i am logged in to my google account)

Comment: an IP address is not a location.

Comment: and I think using your google account probably gives everyone way more information than just a geo-IP based location estimate...

Comment: [A useful interactive diagram](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Proxy/VPN. You will be visible as the targeted location after a sucessfull connect.

There are serveral free versions out there (e.g TunnelBear for Windows).
I'm currently using proxychain on my Fedora machine.

For proxychain I recommend using Socks5. Here you can find some addresses: https://www.socks-proxy.net/

As crovers mentioned, you're never 100% protected from 3rd parties locating you, as there must be a point, where your packages have go through. But via proxy/VVPN/tor it's way more difficult to track you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean without ANY third party knowing about it, no.  IP Routing works by passing packets from one router to another and packets have to ultimately get back to your actual IP address somehow, meaning if all the third parties you route through have logs and co-operate together, they could follow you back.

If you mean without a particular party knowing about it, then sure.  Going through TOR will make you appear as if you were in the location of the TOR exit node.  Going through a VPN will make you appear as if you were wherever the VPN exit point is.  Going through someone else's systems will make you appear to be coming from those systems.  But for VPN and TOR, it is likely that wherever you are going can tell you are routing through TOR/a vpn - TOR exit nodes are known, VPN systems can be too.  They won't know where you actually are, but they may well know you aren't where you say you are.

Comment: What about the following scenrio: I was thinking about setting a private open VPN connection. Let say when I want my laptop to act as if I am in Sweden, I use a real computer in Sweden and set up a VPN connection form that machine. Then i connect from my home laptop to this private VPN connection. Do you think in that case it will be still possible for third parties to figure out what I am doing (i.e. that i am "manipulating" my location)

Comment: If "third parties" includes your ISP(s), they could - they can see the vpn tunnel in and the activity out.  If you discount the ISP, likely not.